# how to group by Archives in sharepoint blog

Tags: blog

In the middle of the page right hand side of this link http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/default.aspx i saw and liked the idea of grouping the archives by month view. Is there any way that i could do that in MOSS 2007 using OOB. or anyone could help me if i could do that with simple coding.

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

I checked the pages html source, and from what I see, they just created a list with all posts, only displaying its month and year. A custom javascript was used to group the items, grouping by month, year.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/blog/Scripts/archivewp.js"></script>
```